# Mobile menu (js) not loading on WordPress WPML site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, responsive-design, wpml

Using WPML on my custom WordPress theme, which is a bilingual English/French site. My mobile menu works fine on the main language (English) site, and not at all on French. Think it's a JS issue, but I'm not familiar with Javascript and looking for help. :)

Background: I took over this WordPress site from another developer who had used a version of the Bones starter theme (Bones-LESS) to create the site. He had used Multilingual Press as a translation plug-in; I removed it and installed WPML (http://wpml.org), which I'm more familiar with.

On screens < 768px, the horizontal navigation menu is replaced by a drop-down "hamburger" menu. The mobile menu works fine on English (main language) pages, but doesn't drop-down/load on French (translated language) pages.

(I used Firefox's "Responsive Design View" with touch enabled to test this on desktop. Can also test on iPhones).

And after reading this thread — https://wpml.org/forums/topic/some-js-is-not-loading/ — I'm assuming it has something to do with the Javascript for the mobile menu not loading due to WPML appending the "/fr" to the URL, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it.

Thank you! Please let me know if there's any further information I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `#menu-main-menu-french` so in your *js* file change:

`$mainNav.find('#menu-main-menu')`

to

`$mainNav.find('>ul')`

in all instances.

---

Or you can manually add a default class/id to your menu.

Comment: You could also see this breaking your js in the console.